# Android NDK Thread invalid use of non-static member function

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, opencv, android-ndk

I need to use threads in my android application because I am doing image processing w/ native opencv. Here is my code:

```
void Detector::processBinary(Mat &binary) {
    //do stuff
}

void Detector::Detect() {
   ...
   thread t1(processBinary, binary);
   t1.join();
}
```

However, I get the error "invalid use of non-static member function" from thread t1(processBinary, binary) whenever I try to run the app. This line, however, works perfectly in visual studio. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which tool chain are you using with Visual Studio?  A member function is not a valid 1st parameter for the constructor of `std::thread`.

Comment: where can I find this in vs2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use member function, that needs `this` argument (it must be called on some object). There are two alternatives:

Use static class function (or non-class function at all):

```
void processBinary(Mat &binary) {
    //do stuff
}

void Detector::Detect() {
   ...
   thread t1(processBinary, binary);
   t1.join();
}
```

Or pass proper arguments if we want utilize member function:

```
void Detector::processBinary(Mat &binary) {
    //do stuff
}

void Detector::Detect() {
   ...
   thread t1(&Detector::processBinary, *this, binary);
   t1.join();
}
```

Comment: Mostly worked. I needed to add std::ref(binary) to get rid of some other errors that popped up. Thanks for the help!